# Simple DFT Lowpass

Tags: c#, fft, dft

I'm having some trouble making a simple lowpass filter with a DFT. In the end, I hope to be able to pitch-shift audio in real time, but as it stands I can't even get this right. I have no training in this area, I only know that FFTs change waves to frequencies and iFFTs do that back, and a couple of other things I've read. To bo honest I'm surprised it works as well as it does so far. Anyway here's the code:

```
        byte[] samples = new byte[20000000];
        int spos = 0;
```

`samples` is filled here with 8Bit Unsigned PCM. `spos` <- number of samples

```
        int samplesize = 128;
        int sampleCount = spos / samplesize;
        frequencies = new System.Numerics.Complex[sampleCount][];
        for (int i = 0; i < sampleCount; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sample " + i + " / " + sampleCount);
            frequencies[i] = new System.Numerics.Complex[samplesize];
            for (int j = 0; j < samplesize; j++)
            {
                frequencies[i][j] = (float)(samples[i * samplesize + j] - 128) / 128.0f;
            }
            dft.Radix2Forward(frequencies[i], MathNet.Numerics.IntegralTransforms.FourierOptions.Default);
        }

        int shiftUp = 1000; //1khz
        int fade = 2; //8 sample fade.
        int kick = frequencies[0].Length * shiftUp / rate;
```

So now I've calculated a bunch of DFTs for 128 sample portions of the input. `kick` is (I hope) the number of samples in the DFT that span 1000Hz. I.E since `frequencies.Length / 2` contains frequency amplitude data up to `rate/2` Hz, then `frequencies[0].Length / 2 * shiftUp / (rate / 2)` = `frequencies[0].Length * shiftUp / rate` should give me the right value

```
        for (int i = 0; i < sampleCount; i++)
        {
```

This is the part I have trouble with. Without it, the output sounds great! This skips both index 0 and index 64. Both of these have a complex component of 0, and I recall reading somewhere that the value at index 0 was important...

```
            for (int j = 0; j < frequencies[i].Length; j++)
            {
                if (j == 0 || j == 64)
                    continue;
                if (j < 64)
                {
                    if (!(j < kick + 1))
                    {
                        frequencies[i][j] = 0;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!(j - 64 > 63 - kick))
                    {
                        frequencies[i][j] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Finally it undoes the transform

```
            dft.Radix2Inverse(frequencies[i], MathNet.Numerics.IntegralTransforms.FourierOptions.Default);
```

...tosses it back in the samples array

```
            for (int j=0; j<samplesize; j++)
                samples[i * samplesize + j] = (byte)(frequencies[i][j].Real * 128.0f + 128.0f);
        }
```

...chucks it into a file

```
        BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite("sound"));
        for (int i = 0; i < spos; i++)
        {
            bw.Write(samples[i]);
        }
        bw.Close();
```

...then I import it into Audacity to murder my ears with artifacts.

The spectral display shows that the code works, to an extent

[image: The bottom one is the output of the code]

However there's these annoying highpitched crackling sounds that occur throughout the entire song. I've heard something about the Gibbs phenomenon and a window function, but I don't really know how to apply that here. The `fade` variable is my best attempt at a window function: everything past the 1000hz mark fades to 0 in 2 samples.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Not my area...but isn't Gibbs the fact that you can't hit your target level without over or undershooting it?

Comment: @Ritch Melton I'm not too sure either...

Comment: I think im getting closer now: the problem seems to be inbetween the samples: it makes a small click sound as it jumps between the two. I think I understand now where the window goes... sampleSize != sampleSpacing then window interpolate.....

Comment: Yup that made things better. Lots better. I'll just clean up what are probably some glitches in my windowing thingy and post the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that I was right (yay): Every 1024 samples I was getting a click sound which made the audio sound awful. To fix this, I faded inbetween many short overlapping chunks of filtered audio. It's not fast, but it works, and I'm pretty sure this is what they mean by "windowing"

```
public class OggDFT
{
    int sample_length;
    byte[] samples;
    DragonOgg.MediaPlayer.OggFile f;
    int rate = 0;
    System.Numerics.Complex[][] frequencies;
    DiscreteFourierTransform dft = new DiscreteFourierTransform();
    int samplespacing = 128;
    int samplesize = 1024;
    int sampleCount;

    public void ExampleLowpass()
    {
        int shiftUp = 1000; //1khz
        int fade = 2; //8 sample fade.
        int halfsize = samplesize / 2;
        int kick = frequencies[0].Length * shiftUp / rate;
        for (int i = 0; i < sampleCount; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < frequencies[i].Length; j++)
            {
                if (j == 0 || j == halfsize)
                    continue;
                if (j < halfsize)
                {
                    if (!(j < kick + 1))
                    {
                        frequencies[i][j] = 0;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!(j - halfsize > halfsize - 1 - kick))
                    {
                        frequencies[i][j] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            dft.BluesteinInverse(frequencies[i], MathNet.Numerics.IntegralTransforms.FourierOptions.Default);
        }
    }

    public OggDFT(DragonOgg.MediaPlayer.OggFile f)
    {
        Complex[] c = new Complex[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            c[i] = i;
        ShiftComplex(-2, c, 5, 10);


        this.f = f;

        //Make a 20MB buffer.
        samples = new byte[20000000];
        int sample_length = 0;

        //This block here simply loads the uncompressed data from the ogg file into a nice n' large 20MB buffer. If you want to use the same library as I've used, It's called DragonOgg (If you cant tell by the namespace)
        while (sample_length < samples.Length)
        {
            var bs = f.GetBufferSegment(4096); //Get ~4096 bytes (does not gurantee that 4096 bytes will be returned.
            if (bs.ReturnValue == 0)
                break; //End of file

            //Set the rate
            rate = bs.RateHz;

            //Display some loading info:
            Console.WriteLine("seconds: " + sample_length / rate);

            //It's stereo so we want half the data.
            int max = bs.ReturnValue / 2;

            //Buffer overflow care.
            if (samples.Length - sample_length < max)
                max = samples.Length - sample_length;

            //The copier.
            for (int j = 0; j < max; j++)
            {
                //I'm using j * 2 here because I know that the input audio is 8Bit Stereo, and we want just one mono channel. So we skip every second one.
                samples[sample_length + j] = bs.Buffer[j * 2];
            }

            sample_length += max;
            if (max == 0)
                break;
        }
        sampleCount = (sample_length - 1) / samplespacing + 1;
        frequencies = new System.Numerics.Complex[sampleCount][];
        for (int i = 0; i < sample_length; i += samplespacing)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sample---" + i + " / " + sample_length);
            System.Numerics.Complex[] sample;
            if (i + samplesize > sample_length)
                sample = new System.Numerics.Complex[sample_length - i];
            else
                sample = new System.Numerics.Complex[samplesize];
            for (int j = 0; j < sample.Length; j++)
            {
                sample[j] = (float)(samples[i + j] - 128) / 128.0f;
            }
            dft.BluesteinForward(sample, MathNet.Numerics.IntegralTransforms.FourierOptions.Default);
            frequencies[i / samplespacing] = sample;
        }

        //Perform the filters to the frequencies
        ExampleLowpass();

        //Make window kernel thingy
        float[] kernel = new float[samplesize / samplespacing * 2];
        for (int i=0; i<kernel.Length; i++)
        {
            kernel[i] = (float)((1-Math.Cos(2*Math.PI*i/(kernel.Length - 1)))/2);
        }

        //Apply window kernel thingy
        for (int i = 0; i < sample_length; i++)
        {
            int jstart = i / samplespacing - samplesize / samplespacing + 1;
            int jend = i / samplespacing;
            if (jstart < 0) jstart = 0;
            float ktotal = 0;
            float stotal = 0;
            for (int j = jstart; j <= jend; j++)
            {
                float kernelHere = 1.0f;
                if (jstart != jend)
                    kernelHere = kernel[(j - jstart) * kernel.Length / (jend + 1 - jstart)];
                int index = i - j * samplespacing;
                stotal += (float)frequencies[j][index].Real * kernelHere;
                ktotal += kernelHere;
            }
            if (ktotal != 0)
            {
                stotal /= ktotal;
                samples[i] = (byte)(stotal * 128 * 0.9f + 128);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("BAD " + jstart + " " + jend + " sec: " + ((float)i / rate));
                samples[i] = (byte)(stotal * 128 * 0.9f + 128);
            }
        }

        BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite("sound"));
        for (int i = 0; i < sample_length; i++)
        {
            bw.Write(samples[i]);
        }
        bw.Close();
    }
}
```

If you want to compile this, you'll need DragonOgg (http://sourceforge.net/projects/dragonogg/) and MathNet.Numerics (http://mathnetnumerics.codeplex.com/)

I hope it helps someone - I don't know about how StackOverflow licences by default, but this code as it stands is public domain.

On further thought, I decided I could achieve an approximated effect much easier by simply "blurring" the samples to get a basic low pass filter. A high pass filter can be made by subtracting the result of the low pass.

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel.  Look up overlap add and overlap save fast convolution filtering using the FFT.  It's described in many DSP technique textbooks.